# A special shopping cart price rule

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules, ce-1.6.2.0

I am trying to add a special shopping cart price rule where a product is assigned to multiple categories and i want define a discount on a particular category
the scenario is : There are two categories

1. Category 1 , Category 2
2. A Product is assigned to both categories
3. If a product is comes in the cart from category 1 there should be discount on cart and if product is also on Category 2 no-discount should be applied.

What i have done for now is attached in the image below.

[image]

Any idea how this can be achieve ?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

1.Create custom local module
2.config.xml required options:

```
   <global>
        <events>
            <checkout_cart_product_add_after>
                <observers>
                    <your_module_unique_node>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>My_Module_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>checkoutCartProductAddAfter</method>
                    </your_module_unique_node>
                </observers>
            </checkout_cart_product_add_after>
        </events>
        <models>
            <salesrule>
                <rewrite>
                    <rule_condition_product>My_Module_Model_Rule_Condition_Product</rule_condition_product>
                </rewrite>
            </salesrule>
        </models>
    </global>
```

3. Add row_config field to sales_flat_quote_item table via your installer:

```
$installer->getConnection()->addColumn($this->getTable('sales_flat_quote_item'), 'row_config', 'varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL');
```

4.Rewrite /app/code/core/Mage/SalesRule/Model/Rule/Condition/Product.php as following into your module folder /app/code/local/My/Module/Model/Rule/Condition/Product.php:

```
class My_Module_Model_Rule_Condition_Product extends Mage_Rule_Model_Condition_Product_Abstract
{
protected function _addSpecialAttributes(array &$attributes)
    {
        parent::_addSpecialAttributes($attributes);
        $attributes['quote_item_qty'] = Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Quantity in cart');
        $attributes['quote_item_price'] = Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Price in cart');
        $attributes['quote_item_row_total'] = Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Row total in cart');
        $attributes['quote_item_row_config'] = Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Row config in cart');
    }

public function validate(Varien_Object $object)
    {
        $product = false;
        if ($object->getProduct() instanceof Mage_Catalog_Model_Product) {
            $product = $object->getProduct();
        } else {
            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                ->load($object->getProductId());
        }

        $product
            ->setQuoteItemQty($object->getQty())
            ->setQuoteItemPrice($object->getPrice()) // possible bug: need to use $object->getBasePrice()
            ->setQuoteItemRowTotal($object->getBaseRowTotal())
            ->setQuoteItemRowConfig($object->getRowConfig());

        return parent::validate($product);
    }
}
```

6. Create observer /app/code/local/My/Module/Model/Observer.php:

```
class My_Module_Model_Observer{
function checkoutCartProductAddAfter($observer)
{
    $quoteItem = $observer->getEvent()->getQuoteItem();
    $config    = $quoteItem->getRowConfig();
    if (Mage::getSingleton('catalog/session')->getLastVisitedCategoryId()) {
        $config = $config . '|C' . Mage::getSingleton('catalog/session')->getLastVisitedCategoryId() . '|';
    }
    $quoteItem->setRowConfig($config);
}
}
```

Observer fires when you add some product to cart and it add last visited category id to the cart item as "|C12|", there 12 is some category id.
Finally you can create shopping cart price rules for cart item with particular category:
[image]
Here is my result:
[image]

P.S: My Magento version is 1.7.0.2 and I don't know this snippet works for your version, but you can use this logic.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible by default. The relation product<->category is a many to many relation that only makes sense in the catalog listing and managing section. When adding a product in the cart the relation is "valid" only in one direction: product->category (is checked if product X is/is not in category Y)
You are adding the product entity to the cart. The cart does not remember the category you come from.
In theory you could implement this, but I don't exactly the cost of this.
You will have to pass to the `addToCart` method an additional parameter telling the category it comes from that you should add to the `quote_item` entity (a new field in `sales_flat_quote_item` and `sales_flat_quote_address_item` tables). Also you will have to modify the behavior of the cart rules to take into account your new field.
This is how I would do it if I had to.